# Chrome developer search in files using regex

Tags: regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Chrome's developer tools, we get text box to search all the loaded files (CSS/JS). Along with it there is an option to search by regex. It looks like it is not supporting regular expressions. I want to search exact match string but I'm not able to do it. E.g. I want to search work "func" which should be exact match. I tried `^func$` but it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Lose the enclosing `/` delimiters - they are for use in JavaScript only.

Comment: @Alex edited the question. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "exact match"? `^string$` means that a String (in the case of Chrome a line) only can contains that string.

Comment: in my case exact match means exact word match. like when we search in editors like notepad++ with check "match whole word only"

Comment: *whole word only* would be `\bfunc\b` as it stands your re matches `<start of line>func<end of line>` which is quite different.

Comment: Thank you Alex. it was simple but was troubling me while searching. \bfunc\b working fine for me.